# Admob - onFailedToReceiveAd must be called on the main UI thread

Tags: admob

I have an Android app that contains an Admob banner on the main screen.

I have set up Mediation with Admob, InMobi and Mobfox. All works fine, the banner ads show.

However, I have recently added in JumpTap and MDotM.

When my app tries to get ads for these two added networks, I get the following message.

Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.jumptap.JumpTapAdapter
03-14 01:10:11.243  14690-14733/com.horseboxsoftware.MSP W/Ads﹕ onFailedToReceiveAd must be called on the main UI thread.

Then the next network in the mediation waterfall gets to display the ad. I would really likt to be able to serve ads for these two recently added networks too.

Here is the code in my Activity that adds the adview

```
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
        AdView av = new AdView(this);
        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequestBanner;
        adRequestBanner = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(Global.johnsPhone).build();
        av.setAdUnitId(Global.getBannerAdId());
        av.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        ll.addView(av);
        av.loadAd(adRequestBanner);
```

As I said, it all works fine for MobFox, InMobi and AdMob. It is only Jumptap and MdotM that seem to have this problem.

All suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the Jumptap and MdotM mediation adapters. I would take it up with their support teams.